# Gracefuly catch segmentation fault that occured in loaded dynamic library

Tags: c#, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a *.NET 4.5* console application that use external *dynamic libraries* and I don't have access to the sources of those libraries. The problem is that those DLLs may raise a *segmentation fault* signal and when this happens, the whole process is immediately terminated. My current solution is to run this dll-dependent  code as a separate process, and then retrieve the result, but I've noticed that this solution is not very efficient.

To illustrate my issue, I've made a sample code:

```c
#include <signal.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void err(void)
{
    raise(SIGSEGV);
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("segFault.dll")]
        extern static void err();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.Write("started");
                err();
                Console.WriteLine("running");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With such setup, I'll never reach the "running" nor the "Exception:" code, because the whole process will be terminated while reaching the segfault signal.
I have tried to mess with Application Domains but also without any great success.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("segFault.dll")]
        extern static void err();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!args.Any())
            {
                AppDomain.CreateDomain("testdomain")
                    .ExecuteAssemblyByName("ConsoleApp", "1");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            try
            {
                Console.Write("started");
                err();
                Console.WriteLine("running");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to bridge the P/Invoke execution using a simple wrapper and then dynamically load that wrapper to the main executable, and also, without any success.

```cs
// Bridge.dll
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace Bridge
{
    public static class Bridge
    {
        [DllImport("segFault.dll")]
        public static extern void err();
    }
}

// Main Executable
using System;
using System.Reflection;
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly.Load("Bridge").GetType("Bridge.Bridge")
                .GetMethod("err").Invoke(null, null);
            Console.WriteLine("This code will not execute");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try installing your custom handler for `SIGSEGV` as described for instance [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32799720/2846483), but you have to know what you are doing. `SIGSEGV` means the unamaged memory of your process might be "damaged", so your whole application or even the runtime might be in a corrupted/undefined state then.

Comment: @dymanoid sadly this answer is all about catching the segfault signal using the C language, I do not have the ability to modify my DLLs so I need to take care about that in the C# language.

Comment: You still can create a small native module and load into your app without touching the DLLs. The `SIGSEGV` is handled at process level, not at module level.

Comment: can you please elaborate further on that topic? How can I wrap already compiled C++ DLL into module to execute it using C# assembly?

Comment: You don't need that. Just create a new native module, use the code from the answer I referenced (it installs the signal handler for the *whole process*) and then just call the "installer" function of that module using P/Invoke in your managed application.